# MySQL - Multiple equivalencies in WHERE clause

Tags: mysql, where-clause, equivalence

I was wondering if there is a difference between the following two `WHERE` clauses in MySQL:

```
WHERE a.Id = b.Id = c.Id
```

vs.

```
WHERE a.Id = b.Id and b.Id = c.Id
```

I am getting different results for these two queries in the following SQLFiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/725396/3

Comment: Use `Inner Join` instead

Comment: Hmmm, why does that fix things?

Comment: I've never seen that before. Are you sure it's not just evaluating one of those equivalences and applying it as an Intoolean to the next? (Ok, yes, I did just coin a term. I mean a Boolean, which is subsequently reinterpreted as an integer with value 0 or 1.) Or is that actually valid syntax in MySQL?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As per the [MySQL doco for an expression](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/expressions.html), your expression `a = b = c` uses the following form of `boolean_primary`:

```
comparison_operator: = | >= | > | <= | < | <> | !=
boolean_primary:
    boolean_primary comparison_operator predicate
```

and is therefore equivalent to:

```
(a = b) = c
```

This means you'll get a *truth* value from `a = b` and then compare *that* with `c`.

In MySQL, the `boolean` type is [equivalent to `tinyint(1)`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/numeric-type-overview.html), where `0` is false and anything else is true. Hence it's simply an integral value which can be compared with another.

Further, the result of a comparison *expression* like `a = b` [will always return](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html) `0` for false, `1` for true, or NULL if any input is NULL.

Therefore, for the expression `a = b = c` to be true, none of them are allowed to be NULL, and one of the following must be true:

- `a` is equal to `b`, and `c` is equal to `1`; or
- `a` is not equal to `b`, and `c` is equal to `0`.

That's almost certainly not what you want, the correct form is the second one.

Comment: Which is indeed what is happening, and here's [a fiddle to prove it](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/95b63/2)

Comment: Wow, that makes perfect sense. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think the difference is that in the first WHERE all three ids must be equal, whereas in the latter a.id should be equal to b.id and b.id should be equal to c.id but it doesn't mean that a.id should be equal to c.id.

Comment: In what universe does `a = b` and `b = c` but `a != c`? :-)

Comment: ) yes. doesn't make sense.